# C++ Generate random numbers in format HH:MM

Tags: c++, time, format

I have the following problem
I need to write a function that generates a random hour and a random minute - this is the start time, and generate the end time (+ 1.5 H)
My problem is that when I have eg 7 o'clock or 7:7 and then I need to format this to display the time in such way: 07:07 - 08:37
I tried to do it with the help of IF statements, but for every possibility, the cosmic amount of IF's came out
Is there any better way to generate this?
I can not put time in the string

Comment: Can you do the minutes? That is, can you print `25` as "25" and `7` as "07"? How many **`if`** statements do you need for that? Once you have that working, can you do the hours? Do you then know how to combine them?

Comment: Look into [<iomanip>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/) for your 0 padding. Also why not generate just the minutes and then use `%` and `/` to get hours and minutes?

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like this:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int hour = 7;
    int minute = 7;

    std::string timeStr;

    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << hour << ":" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << minute;
        timeStr = ss.str();
    }

    std::cout << timeStr;

    return 0;
}
```

Explanation:

`setw()` sets the field width to be used on output operations.

`setfill()` sets c as the stream's fill character.

Reference:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setfill/